# VT set in BIOS but not showing vmx CPU flag on OS

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtualbox, openstack

I have Dell `XPS M1530` Laptop and CPU is `Intel Core2 Duo T8300 2.8Ghz`. I have set Visualization Technology On in BIOS and install Ubuntu 12.04 on `VirtualBox` but in `/proc/cpuinfo`  `vmx` cpu flag doesn't appear. Even in VirtualBox i have enable VT-x option, Am i missing something? I want to install openstack on it but without VT support i can't run nested VM. Please suggest.

EDIT:

I have attached CPU identifying tool screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this processor model is correct? Can't even find it in [intel website](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/26548)

Comment: sorry it was T8300 i mistype :(

Comment: It is the problem with the BIOS software, you can try updating your BIOS and/or contacting Dell. If that also doesn't work, there is nothing else you can do other than get a new computer (or write your own BIOS)

Comment: But on Intel Web site they are saying this model of CPU supported `VT` does that means my hardware is supported right?

Comment: Even if intel supports it, its in the hands of your BIOS whether it actually works or not. If the BIOS is not coded properly, like in your case, things like this can happen.

Comment: I have upgrade BIOS with latest one but still its not showing VMX CPU flag. Now who am i blame?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you have enabled VT-x in the BIOS and VirtualBox is able to utilize it from a Windows host, but it is not presenting VT support through to the guest operating systems?

If that is correct: that is because - to my knowledge - VirtualBox does not support *virtualizing* VT support for guests. See this ticket for some discussion: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this SO question? [VirtualBox and vmdk vmx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505021/virtualbox-and-vmdk-vmx-files)

For some reason it was closed by SO, but seems to have good information.:

VMDK/VMX are VMWare file formats but you can use it with VirtualBox, just create a new Virtual Machine and when asks for a hard disk choose "Use an existing hard disk" and click on the "button with folder and green arrow image on the combo box right" which opens Virtual Media Manager, it looks like this (you can open it directly pressing CTRL+D on main window or in File > Virtual Media Manager menu)...

And then you can add the VMDK/VMX hard disk image and setup it for your virtual machine :)